# mysql8: Incorrect datetime value: '2016-02', what can I do?

Tags: mysql, data-cleaning

For example, there are two tables like this:

1.original table

| date_str |
| --- |
| 2016-02 |
| 2016-02-02 |

2.new table(Created based on the original table, an additional is date field is added)

| date_str | is_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-02 |  |
| 2016-02-02 |  |

`date_str` in the original table should be in date format, but the actual field type is varchar, and the data stored is also a variety of, not only date format strings, but also other formats (for example, 123, abc, etc.).
I will now extract the `date_str` field from the original table and insert it into the new table. Check whether it is in date format when inserting, and if not, fill `DATE_FORMAT` in the `is_date` field

My SQL statement is:

```sql
INSERT INTO new_table ( date_str, is_date ) 
SELECT
ot.date_str  AS date_str,
CASE    
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT( ot.date_str, '%Y-%m-%d' ) IS NULL 
    THEN 'DATE_FORMAT' 
END AS is_date 
FROM original_table ot
```

If you execute this SQL, you will get an error: **Incorrect DateTime value: '2016-02'**

I looked it up on the Internet and needed to adjust the MySQL configuration file `my.cnf` to remove the sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from the configuration file, but I didn't want to do so, because it would affect other tables.

Comment: Is there a day of the month that you could use to complete the information needed for a date?

Comment: `sql_mode` can be set on a session basis. SQL is better with structured data (its in the acronym). Clean data rather than working around it.

Comment: That *is* an invalid datetime, caused by application bug*s* and can't be recovered - which *day* in February do you expect back? Don't store dates as strings in the first place, use `DATE`. If you want to store periods, use a different field just for periods.

Comment: What do you expect is_date to look like after the insert based on your published sample data.

Comment: Does the text come from a source that uses reduced-precision ISO8601 date strings? MySQL doesn't allow this, neither do PostgreSQL , SQL Server or Oracle. I think Ingress allowed this. PostgreSQL and Oracle have *interval* types to represent durations, eg 1 year 5 months. How you handle this depends on the application and how want that value to behave in queries, what the existing queries are. Do you want that row to be included in every query that covers a date in February?

Comment: This is a very old table, and the data is now in this format. Now I've added the field is_date to check if the value under the date_str field is in date format, if it's not, then fill DATE_FORMAT in, if it is, then fill nothing in. @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: If it's an old table you'll be able to find out what that value means and how it's used. It's no use insisting this is a date format, this will only prevent you from finding a solution. Dates have no formats. That field is text, not a date. How *is* it used? Does that represent the entire month of February? And why are you trying to cast that string to a date now? What result do you expect? *All these matter*

Comment: For example, if you want to validate, you can use a regular expression. If you want to format the value for display on a client - what do you expect to show for an entire month? You *could* append `-01` to get a specific date, but only you know whether that's appropriate here or not

Comment: If you want to filter by that date string, things get tricky, especially if you want to take advantage of indexing. Indexes on text columns allow exact or prefix searches using lexical sorting only. That means `2016-02` comes before `2016-02-01`. If you want to match a February date with that value, you'll have to use some tricks.  You could use `@myISOParam LIKE date_str + '%'` *BUT* that can't use any indexes that cover `date_str`, forcing a full table scan. Maybe `date_str = @myIsoParam OR date_str=LEFT(@myIsoParam,8)` ?

Comment: date_str is originally a date-format field, but the field type is varchar, resulting in a variety of data, not only the date format, but also other strings, such as: 123, abc, etc. All I have to do now is determine the records in the date_str field that are not in date format. @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. If you insist, you won't understand what the problem is so won't be able to find a solution. `DATE_FORMAT` works on *date values*, not strings. The only reason it works here is because MySQL implicitly parses the strings to dates so it can format them to strings. The method that parses strings to dates is `STR_TO_DATE`, which returns NULL if the string can't be parsed

Answer (score 1):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) instead of `DATE_FORMAT`. That method parses strings into dates and returns NULL if the string can't be parsed.

```
SELECT 
    IF(STR_TO_DATE( date_str, '%Y-%m-%d' ) IS NULL,1,0) as is_date
FROM table_name
```

Dates in all databases except SQLite are binary values, they have no format. Most databases will parse strings into dates implicitly though. If the parse fails, the entire query fails.

[DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) itself expects a date value to format into a string.

The only reason the query works at all is that MySQL implicitly parses the string into a date before passing it to `DATE_FORMAT`. When the implicit cast fails, the entire query fails. At that point, `DATE_FORMAT` hasn't been called yet.

This example, also [shown in this dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UD0zyktA), creates a table with some text fields and calculates the `is_date` fields.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    date_str varchar(50),
    is_date boolean null
);
INSERT INTO MyTable(date_str)
VALUES
('2016-02-16'),
('2016-02'),
('Banana');
```

A query with `STR_TO_DATE` returns the following result

```
SELECT ID,IF(STR_TO_DATE(date_str,'%Y-%m-%d') is null,0,1) as is_date
FROM MyTable;

------
ID  is_date
1   1
2   0
3   0
```

To update the table we need to use `IGNORE`. `STR_TO_DATE` generates a warning if the value doesn't match. SELECT doesn't care but UPDATE/INSERT will convert the warning to an error :

```
UPDATE IGNORE MyTable     
    Set MyTable.is_date=IF(STR_TO_DATE(date_str,'%Y-%m-%d'),0,1)
;

SELECT * 
FROM MyTable;
-----

ID  date_str    is_date
1   2016-02-16  0
2   2016-02     1
3   Banana      1
```

Comment: Error : Incorrect datetime value: '2016-02' for function str_to_date.There is also an insert operation : INSERT INTO table_name ( is_date ) .

Comment: What did you *actually* try? `select STR_TO_DATE( 'accd', '%Y-%m-%d' ) as is_date` works just fine in MySQL 8 and returns `NULL` as [this dbFiddle shows](https://dbfiddle.uk/371sgF4T). As for the query, I assumed that `INSERT` wasn't a real query because it would just insert a bunch of `1` and `0`s to a table without any relation to the original rows.

Comment: [select STR_TO_DATE( '2016-02', '%Y-%m-%d' )](https://dbfiddle.uk/idebeSU8) also works fine

Comment: I made a mistake, in fact, there are two tables, one is the old table (there is a field date_str), the other is my new table (contains the old table date_str field, while adding a is_date field), and then check the data date_str from the old table, and check whether it is a date format. The original date_str value and the checksum value is_date are then inserted into the new table.

Answer (score -1):

You can temporarily set the `sql_model` attribute of the mysql configuration file `my.cnf`, remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, and then add it back after the sql is executed. The sql is:

```
set sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

INSERT INTO new_talbe ( date_str, is_date ) 
SELECT
ot.date_str AS date_str,
CASE    
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT( ot.date_str, '%Y-%m-%d' ) IS NULL 
    THEN 'DATE_FORMAT' 
END AS is_date 
FROM original_table ot;

set sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Or use regular expressions.

Comment: Is that `INSERT INTO table_name ( is_date ) ` the actual query? That will insert a bunch of new rows with all fields set to NULL except `is_date`, which won't have any relation to the original rows

Comment: I rephrased the question.